# Firebase reject new users subscription

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm workimg with Android Studio and Firebase. Everything worked fine but for a while now it has been impossible to accept a new user in my application.
After the registration has been validated, my application restarts the registration process from the beginning.
Android Studio returns the following error even though I haven't changed anything since May 27, 2019:

```
E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
```

I tried to update the database rules like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=****} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Here my Main Activty:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener,
        OnFragmentInteractionListener, InternetCallbackListener{

FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
private GoogleApiClient client;
protected GoogleHelper googleHelper;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
```

//[...]

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (!isTaskRoot()) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken("xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, Statics.REQUEST_SIGN_IN);
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                //            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
```

//[...]

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

// Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        //updateUI(currentUser);


        mAuth.signInAnonymously()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());

        String uuid = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        dbHelper2.getUser(uuid, new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot document) {
                      thisUser = document.getData();

                      if (thisUser == null) {
                          // go to user profile activity to register
                          Intent i = new Intent(context, SubscriptionActivity.class);
                          //i.putExtra("userId", null);
                          context.startActivity(i);
                      }
            }
        });
```

//[...]

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResult");
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == Statics.REQUEST_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                // ...
            }
        }
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: are you on a free plan?

Comment: you probably ran out of storage, in your project. update to better plan if you are not in a free plan, share the logs

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I'm going to check that. Yes,I'm on a free plan. But my app is in development and I just have 17 registered users as testers.

Comment: check the usage here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/firestore/usage.   see if you have hit any of the limits.

Comment: @yoga   I checked the usages and everything is ok under the allowed quotas of my plan. Does anyone have another idea?

Comment: no one has encountered this problem? Am I really the only one or does no one understand my question?